# Does OS 10.9.3 work with multiple external 4k monitors?

Tags: macos, display, macbook-pro

Have a Late-2013 15" rMBP running OS X 10.9.3 with an external 4k-capable Samsung LU28D590DS/ZA.

Whenever I also connect my Dell 30" non-4K monitor, the screen flashes briefly like the machine is acknowledging that another monitor is attached, but then fails to display output to the 30" monitor.

If I unplug one monitor or the other, I can work with either one at a time, but not both.

Is this a known issue with OS 10.9.3 or limitation of my video card?

EDIT: I used the Console application to test output after plugging the secondary monitor in, and got the following output:

```
6/7/14 11:20:12.048 PM WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280642
6/7/14 11:20:12.052 PM WindowServer[95]: Found 94 modes for display 0x04280642 [94, 0]
6/7/14 11:20:12.089 PM WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003f
6/7/14 11:20:12.089 PM WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003f [1, 0]
6/7/14 11:20:12.089 PM WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0xb42e004
6/7/14 11:20:12.095 PM WindowServer[95]: Found 198 modes for display 0x0b42e004 [198, 0]
6/7/14 11:20:12.125 PM WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f0041
6/7/14 11:20:12.125 PM WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f0041 [1, 0]
6/7/14 11:20:12.147 PM WindowServer[95]: MPServiceForDisplayDevice: Invalid device alias (0)
6/7/14 11:20:12.147 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: GL mask 0x10; bounds (0, 0)[800 x 600], 198 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 4c2d, Model b80, S/N 0, Unit 4, Rotation 0
UUID 0x920f49c656a933f746ca7b36a2115866, ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}
6/7/14 11:20:12.148 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000003c, accelerator 0x000039b7, unit 2, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 2048 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:12.148 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: GL mask 0x5; bounds (-800, 600)[800 x 600], 94 modes available
Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a019, S/N 0, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xf466f621b5fa04a00800cfa6c258decd, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
6/7/14 11:20:12.148 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000003c, accelerator 0x000039b7, unit 2, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 2048 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:12.148 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (1824, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
6/7/14 11:20:12.148 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024502, GL mask 0x00000003, accelerator 0x0000542f, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:12.148 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f0041: GL mask 0x20; bounds (1825, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 5, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
6/7/14 11:20:12.148 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (1826, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, ColorProfile { 4, "DELL U3011"}
6/7/14 11:20:12.403 PM WindowServer[95]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 0.250 second wait for reply from "vmware-vmx" for synchronous notification type 100 (kCGSDisplayWillReconfigure) (CID 0x287a3, PID 1438)
6/7/14 11:20:12.412 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4: Startup Mode 800 x 600, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80005007, ioModeDepth 0x2, IOReturn 0x0
6/7/14 11:20:12.412 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2: Startup Mode 800 x 600, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80004006, ioModeDepth 0x2, IOReturn 0x0
6/7/14 11:20:12.413 PM WindowServer[95]: Display added
6/7/14 11:20:12.413 PM WindowServer[95]: Display removed
6/7/14 11:20:12.414 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: GL mask 0x10; bounds (0, 0)[800 x 600], 198 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 4c2d, Model b80, S/N 0, Unit 4, Rotation 0
UUID 0x920f49c656a933f746ca7b36a2115866, ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}
6/7/14 11:20:12.414 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000003c, accelerator 0x000039b7, unit 2, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 2048 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:12.414 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: GL mask 0x5; bounds (-800, 600)[800 x 600], 94 modes available
Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a019, S/N 0, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xf466f621b5fa04a00800cfa6c258decd, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
6/7/14 11:20:12.415 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000003c, accelerator 0x000039b7, unit 2, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 2048 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:12.415 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (1824, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
6/7/14 11:20:12.415 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024502, GL mask 0x00000003, accelerator 0x0000542f, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:12.415 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f0041: GL mask 0x20; bounds (1825, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 5, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
6/7/14 11:20:12.415 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (1826, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, ColorProfile { 4, "DELL U3011"}
6/7/14 11:20:12.434 PM BetterSnapTool[478]: notification NSConcreteNotification 0x610000052510 {name = NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification; object = <NSApplication: 0x610000115180>}
6/7/14 11:20:12.471 PM WindowServer[95]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x0b42e004 device: 0x7fc5b3001780  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
6/7/14 11:20:12.477 PM WindowServer[95]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280642 device: 0x7fc5b1f055c0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
6/7/14 11:20:13.527 PM WindowServer[95]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "VMware Fusion" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
6/7/14 11:20:13.600 PM WindowServer[95]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "VMware Fusion" after 1.07 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
6/7/14 11:20:14.090 PM WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
6/7/14 11:20:14.125 PM WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
6/7/14 11:20:14.146 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.147 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.171 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.172 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.195 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.196 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.240 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.240 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.411 PM WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
6/7/14 11:20:14.427 PM WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
6/7/14 11:20:14.459 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.460 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.480 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.480 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.523 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.523 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.532 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:14.532 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:17.117 PM WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280642
6/7/14 11:20:17.122 PM WindowServer[95]: Found 94 modes for display 0x04280642 [94, 0]
6/7/14 11:20:17.172 PM WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003f
6/7/14 11:20:17.172 PM WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003f [1, 0]
6/7/14 11:20:17.172 PM WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0xb42e004
6/7/14 11:20:17.182 PM WindowServer[95]: Found 198 modes for display 0x0b42e004 [198, 0]
6/7/14 11:20:17.209 PM WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f0041
6/7/14 11:20:17.209 PM WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f0041 [1, 0]
6/7/14 11:20:17.231 PM WindowServer[95]: MPServiceForDisplayDevice: Invalid device alias (0)
6/7/14 11:20:17.231 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: GL mask 0x10; bounds (0, 0)[800 x 600], 198 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 4c2d, Model b80, S/N 0, Unit 4, Rotation 0
UUID 0x920f49c656a933f746ca7b36a2115866, ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}
6/7/14 11:20:17.232 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000003c, accelerator 0x000039b7, unit 2, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 2048 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:17.232 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: GL mask 0x5; bounds (-800, 600)[800 x 600], 94 modes available
Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a019, S/N 0, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xf466f621b5fa04a00800cfa6c258decd, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
6/7/14 11:20:17.232 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000003c, accelerator 0x000039b7, unit 2, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 2048 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:17.232 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (1824, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
6/7/14 11:20:17.232 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024502, GL mask 0x00000003, accelerator 0x0000542f, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:17.232 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f0041: GL mask 0x20; bounds (1825, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 5, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
6/7/14 11:20:17.232 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (1826, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, ColorProfile { 4, "DELL U3011"}
6/7/14 11:20:17.482 PM WindowServer[95]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 0.250 second wait for reply from "vmware-vmx" for synchronous notification type 100 (kCGSDisplayWillReconfigure) (CID 0x287a3, PID 1438)
6/7/14 11:20:17.491 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4: Startup Mode 800 x 600, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80007007, ioModeDepth 0x2, IOReturn 0x0
6/7/14 11:20:17.491 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2: Startup Mode 800 x 600, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80006006, ioModeDepth 0x2, IOReturn 0x0
6/7/14 11:20:17.492 PM WindowServer[95]: Display added
6/7/14 11:20:17.492 PM WindowServer[95]: Display removed
6/7/14 11:20:17.493 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: GL mask 0x10; bounds (0, 0)[800 x 600], 198 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 4c2d, Model b80, S/N 0, Unit 4, Rotation 0
UUID 0x920f49c656a933f746ca7b36a2115866, ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}
6/7/14 11:20:17.493 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000003c, accelerator 0x000039b7, unit 2, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 2048 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:17.493 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: GL mask 0x5; bounds (-800, 600)[800 x 600], 94 modes available
Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a019, S/N 0, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xf466f621b5fa04a00800cfa6c258decd, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
6/7/14 11:20:17.493 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000003c, accelerator 0x000039b7, unit 2, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 2048 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:17.493 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (1824, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
6/7/14 11:20:17.493 PM WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024502, GL mask 0x00000003, accelerator 0x0000542f, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
6/7/14 11:20:17.493 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f0041: GL mask 0x20; bounds (1825, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 5, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
6/7/14 11:20:17.493 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (1826, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, ColorProfile { 4, "DELL U3011"}
6/7/14 11:20:17.519 PM BetterSnapTool[478]: notification NSConcreteNotification 0x610000052510 {name = NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification; object = <NSApplication: 0x610000115180>}
6/7/14 11:20:17.573 PM WindowServer[95]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x0b42e004 device: 0x7fc5b3001780  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
6/7/14 11:20:17.582 PM WindowServer[95]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280642 device: 0x7fc5b1f055c0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
6/7/14 11:20:18.621 PM WindowServer[95]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "VMware Fusion" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
6/7/14 11:20:18.636 PM WindowServer[95]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "VMware Fusion" after 1.02 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
6/7/14 11:20:19.173 PM WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
6/7/14 11:20:19.209 PM WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
6/7/14 11:20:19.231 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.232 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.257 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.258 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.286 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.286 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.296 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.297 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.490 PM WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
6/7/14 11:20:19.505 PM WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
6/7/14 11:20:19.536 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.537 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.557 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.557 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.593 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.593 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.601 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x0b42e004: Unit 4; ColorProfile { 3, "U28D590"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
6/7/14 11:20:19.636 PM WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280642: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
```

Comment: does it show all monitors in the configuration?

Comment: nope, only 2 at a time

Comment: then there is your answer

Comment: well, my question is whether this is a known limitation. is it?

Comment: I previously had two external, non-4k monitors on this machine without issue.

Comment: In which port is each connected to your MBP? Try toggling [Multi Stream Transport](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht6008) on the 4K

Comment: looks like my monitor, the samsung, is not included in that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the Macbook wasn't working with a 4k monitor and a non-4K monitor both plugged into displayports. When I plugged the non-4k monitor into my HDMI port, it worked, albeit at a less-than-ideal resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, Apple reports that the Retina Display MacBook Pro models can support two external displays up to a 2560x1600 resolution via the Thunderbolt or Thunderbolt 2 ports or one display with a maximum resolution of 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and one display up to a maximum resolution of 1920x1200 (1080p) via HDMI.

http://support.apple.com/kb/SP690

> MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) - Technical Specifications.
>   Display. Retina display: 15.4-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit display with
>   IPS technology; ... on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600
>   pixels on up to two external displays, ..

Mavericks has been know to have some issues with external monitor, most of it was fixed in the 10.9.3.

Set your monitors to correct resolution and try again.

Comment: Buscar...that support article applies to all models before late 2013, which the OP has. Late 2013 MBP's have different tech specs in this regard. For example, http://support.apple.com/kb/SP690

Comment: Welcome. Yes just update. Late 2013 models provide 4k support see under HDMI specs of article provided. Sorry for poor formatting on mobile device now.

Comment: Ah ok, so if I drop the resolution on my 4K monitor, I shouldn't have the issue any longer. Question: would closing my laptop and only using external monitors affect the maximum resolutions possible?

Comment: good question, I do not know, but would think it is possible since the load to the GPU is lowered ! all you can do is try it :) Please check the answer as done so it does not keep pooping up here forever as incomplete.

Comment: so I just tried this, and it turns out that setting the monitors to lower, non-retina resolutions does not change whether or not the second monitor is recognized, nor does closing the clamshell of the laptop. As soon as I unplug one monitor or the other, the other one is instantly recognized by the machine; both are plugged into my thunderbolt ports, which is how I had things set up previously. Any other thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: at this time I would need to see your console report at the time stamp when you plug in the second monitor and the following 10-20 lines

Comment: how do I generate that?

Comment: In your utility folder open the Console app. view all messages. Now plug second monitor in and watch it do. Then select the lines of interest and copy/paste in here

Comment: sorry for the delay, OP updated with this information.

Comment: Unit 4: Startup Mode 3200 x 1800 ? and Unit 2: Startup Mode 1920 x 1200 ? so did you change the resolution on the displays?

Comment: updated the information with all three monitors set at minimum resolution, same issue persists

Comment: Tagging @Buscar웃